# nginx can't disable SSLv3

Tags: nginx, ssl

I'm having an issue trying to disable SSLv3 on my nginx installation.

HTTPS works fine, but I just can't seem to disable SSLv3 and it makes my site vulnerable to the POODLE attack. Also, for some reason the connection is encrypted over 128-bit instead of 256-bit even though I got a 256-bit certificate.

Nginx version: 1.6.2

Here's what I entered into my server block on the site I wanted to use:

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers On;
ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS;
```

Thanks!

Comment: The number of bits isn't the only factor in encryption. Also, the size of the private key used to generate your certificate is certainly not 256-bit, as (for RSA) that would be really weak. The `ssl_protocols` line you use seems correct, so I would check Mozilla's documentation on how to choose the ciphers

Comment: The size is 2048 if I recall correctly. Do you have a link to Mozilla's docs that I can use?

Comment: Thanks gparent for the link to the other post. Was searching alot but couldn't find anything. Thank you, that solved it for me!

Comment: @Svenskunganka http://nginx.com/blog/nginx-poodle-ssl/

Comment: I had set the protocols correctly, but it still wasn't disabled until I set them correctly on ALL virtualhosts on that server.  `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:443 -ssl3` lets you test if SSL3 is enabled and was what gave me the hint in that direction.

Comment: Has anyone find out why? It still accepts SSLv3 even after restarting.

Comment: @Daniel is right, the configuration needs to be applied to all virtual hosts or the surrounding http block. I had the same problem, I only applied it to one server block and it wasn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## 1. Disabling SSLv3

The only line you need to use to make nginx stop using is you first one, ie

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
```

If you still see nginx using SSLv3, then your new configuration has most probably not been applied.

Use `nginx -t` to test your configuration, then reload the service by using:

```
service nginx reload
```

or send a `SIGHUP` signal to the nginx master process.

To check that no error happened and that the configuration reload happened flawlessly, monitor your main `error_log` (the one defined at the highest level, typically `main`) closely. Errors will pop-up there if something is wrong (ie due to SSL certificates or anything not detectable at configuration validation time)

## 2. Ciphers

Ciphers have nothing to do with your key size. They are negociated between client and server to choose common supported cipher suites in order to execute the 4 parts of the SSL protocol where digests/hashes/signatures are needed.

Different qualities of different cipher suites suits better to certain steps than to others.

[More information about cipher suites is available @Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher_suite).